# Laravel mailable is not affected to changes via Sendgrid

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3 (php7.0.1) along with nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu) and redis. On one of my servers when trying to change code of mailable, sometimes it doesn't affect results, eg. I want to change subject of the emails so I edit file and set 
`->subject('New subject')` 
... but emails are being send with old subject ... :/ I assume the file must be cached somewhere, so I've cleaned laravel cache and views, restarted nginx, restarted redis - no result. Can you help me with finding the cause? I would much appreciate some hint on localizing that cached files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using queue instead of send, that has to be the problem.

You probably have something in queue, and Laravel keeps resending that using the old Mailable, since it may cause problems to the existing emails which are already packed and waiting to be send at scheduled time(even though they are not using the same Mailable - like in my case).

Empty/restart your queue, and then it should work.